# Save fb image dynamically to my server

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to save facebook profile image to my server using this code.
This code is working if i put fb ID in place of echo $id; like this ->
$image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/1234728353274856/picture?width=2048&height=1536');

but i need to display id dynamically using php.

I tried by using below code but it doesn't work.

Kindly help.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['FBID']));  {
$id= $_SESSION['FBID'];
$image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/{echo $id;}/picture?width=2048&height=1536');
file_put_contents('C:/wamp/www/fbapp/images/image.jpg', $image);  
?>
```

Comment: Try this : `$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=2048&height=1536";` and then `$image = file_get_contents($url);` * Using double quotes

Comment: Thanks there were two issues with my code.
1) using single quote instead of double
2) using & between width and height.

I solved it and here is the correct code:-

<code>
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=2048&height=15‌​36"; and then $image = file_get_contents($url);
</code>

Comment: What kind of issue? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for replying late but I fixed that issue on the same day. 
this function was not accepting the "&" sign so i just deleted the "&height=1536" and my code works well.